# Reduction with OpenMP: Matrix/tensor operations examples

Tags: c++, openmp, eigen, eigen3

I am trying to learn how to use reduction with OpenMP and was wondering if the following examples can be rewritten with reduction?

Example A: Finding the sum of three matrices/tensors

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/SparseCore> 
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
static const int nx = 128; 
static const int ny = 128; 
static const int nz = 128;

Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3> Tensor1(nx,ny,nz);   
Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3> Tensor2(nx,ny,nz);    
Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3> Tensor3(nx,ny,nz); 
for(int i = 0; i< nx; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j< ny; j++){
            for(int k = 0; k< nz; k++){ 
                Sum(k,i,j) = (Tensor1(k,i,j) + Tensor2(k,i,j) + Tensor3(k,i,j));

            }
        }
    }
```

Example B: Finding separate terms of the cross product of (AxB):

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/SparseCore> 
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
static const int nx = 128; 
static const int ny = 128; 
static const int nz = 128;

double B[3] = {Bx,By,Bz};

Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3> Ax(nx,ny,nz);  
Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3> Ay(nx,ny,nz); 
Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3> Az(nx,ny,nz); 

Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3> Termx(nx,ny,nz);   
Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3> Termy(nx,ny,nz);    
Eigen::Tensor<std::complex<double>, 3> Termz(nx,ny,nz);    

    for(int i = 0; i< nx; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j< ny; j++){
            for(int k = 0; k< nz; k++){ 
                    Termx(k,i,j) = (Az(k,i,j) * By - Ay(k,i,j) * Bz);
                    Termy(k,i,j) =  (Ax(k,i,j) * Bz - Az(k,i,j) * Bx);
                    Termz(k,i,j) =  (Ay(k,i,j) * Bx - Ax(k,i,j) * By);


            }
        }
    }
```

I have not seen examples of reduction with either nested loops or matrices/tensors so I am not sure if the above examples work with reduction or not. Thanks!

Comment: This is apparently an embarrassingly parallel use-case so there is no need for reduction. Besides, AFAIR, Eigen use a C array ordering so I expect the latest dimension to be more contiguous and so the loop order to be inefficient. Even if I am wrong, having `i` for the first loop is inefficient anyway (both for row-major and column-major arrays).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no.

The longer answer is that your examples don't fit with the basic idea of what reduction is intended to accomplish.

Reduction is typically used for a case where all the threads write to a single output. For a really simplistic example, consider normalizing a large matrix, by simply adding up all the numbers, then dividing each by the sum so they're all in the range 0..1.

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<m; j++)
        for (int k=0; k<o; k++)
            sum += matrix[i][j][k];
```

This has a problem: all the threads write to `sum`. To keep meaningful results, the OpenMP runtime serializes access to `sum`, and we gain very little (if anything) from all the threads running in parallel. Depending on the implementation, we might easily be locking and unlocking a mutex every iteration, in which case parallel code might even be quite a lot slower than serial code.

We can use `reduction` to fix that:

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<m; j++)
        for (int k=0; k<o; k++)
            sum += matrix[i][j][k];
```

With this, each thread gets a private variable where it stores its local sum. Then when the threads finish, it does the reduction (using the operator we specified--`+` in this case) and adds all those separate values together.

`reduction` helps when all the threads work together to produce a single value, and we can avoid pressure on that one value by having each thread produce a value independently, and afterwards combine all those independent values.

That doesn't really work in your case, because each of your writes is already to a separate variable from that used by any other thread.

Comment: Would this also work for normalizing a matrix by a specific factor? e.g. ``matrix[i][j][k] = 1.0/(nx*ny*nz) * matrix[i][j][k];``

Comment: @Jamie: at least at first glance, that seems like a reasonable possibility. A lot here depends on exactly how strict you are about what "normalization" means. Strictly speaking, it should give a magnitude of exactly 1, but in a lot of cases (especially some graphics) you're happy with a magnitude "close" to 1 that you can produce quickly.

Comment: @Jamie `matrix[i][j][k] = 1.0/(nx*ny*nz) * matrix[i][j][k];` is again a trivially parallel operation. The reduction is needed for computing the factor in normalization, not for scaling the values with a known factor. So my answer (to above comment) would be **no**.

Comment: Also there is OpenMP syntax for doing reductions on arrays `reduction(+: array[:K][:M][:N])`, but it is only useful in some niche cases/for very small `N`, like maybe summing up a ton of small tensors. Even something like filling a histogram is in my experience faster using atomics than using this technique. Allthough this might just be due to missing optimizations of the final reduction on the OpenMP implementation side.

Comment: @Jamie: Rereading your question above (and reading paleonix's comments) I may have misunderstood what you were asking. I thought you were asking whether `matrix[i][j][k] = 1.0/(nx*ny*nz) * matrix[i][j][k];` could work to do normalization, to which the answer is yes. But if you were asking whether you'd gain much from using OpenMP to do that, I'd agree with paleonix: probably not.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments and feedback this has been very helpful!